# Unable to remove Action Bar in Android tabLayout

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to get rid of the ActionBar in an android app.
here's the manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and here's the styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</resources>
```

I did change the `AppTheme` style to NoActionBar, but the emulator still shows the action bar, What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar` from `MainActivity` entry in the manifest and then run your app.

Answer (score 0):

it's because you are setting wrong theme for your app,`AppTheme` parent should remove action bar

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppThemeNoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeNoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>



</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

stupidly enough, I didn't take a look at the main activity xml, which included an AppBarLayout widget, so I removed it and rearranged the layout, and now no action bar appears

Comment: so it's better to remove question